# List of known bugs for Steema TeeChart Pro v2009/2010 for .NET

Tags: .net, teechart

Is there a list available of known bugs for Steema TeeChart v2009/2010 for .NET? We are developing a MD product and need to keep track of them.

Answer (score 0):

OK, no worries, I found the bugzilla

http://bugs.teechart.net/